# C# - Probing Path to AppData?

Tags: c#

Is it possible to use probing for reference to .dll's in AppData?

`<probing privatePath="libs" />`

This is what im using right now, but I can't reference any folder outside of the folder containing the .exe file.

Is there an alternative way to get it done?

Im attempting this so that my application with around 10 dll files can be somewhat in-dependent and be a single .exe file.
Due to how the dependency files are used, I cant use ILMerge e.t.c

Comment: Have you considered handling AppDomain's assembly resolve event?

Comment: @MickyD I have, When I do it using that, all it does is shutdown which occurs when a dependency didnt load. But using the same path but with App.config it will load (This is using a relative path next to the .exe not with appdata at the moment)

Comment: Consider posting your code.  Good luck! :)

Comment: @MickyD Im using the code from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43311366/8549339